# Opening Spotify app from a reactnative expo app

Tags: react-native, webview, expo, spotify

I am trying to open up Spotify from my React Native Expo app. From there, I want a user to select a song and start playing it.

Right now, I'm using a Webview to open up spotify directly within my application since that seems simplest. However, when tapping a song to play, the web browser prompts a user to download Spotify (instead of just playing the song).

Any suggestions?

```
          <WebView source={{ uri: "https://open.spotify.com/?" }} style={{ flex: 1 }} 
                      onNavigationStateChange={(navState) => {
                        console.log(navState.url);
                      }}
          />
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a workaround. I specified some user agents and now I am able to play music from the webview in my React Native Expo application

Hope this helps someone else!

```
          <WebView source={{ uri: "https://open.spotify.com/?" }} style={{ flex: 1 }} 
                  onNavigationStateChange={(navState) => {
                    console.log(navState.url);
                  }}

                  userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 17_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.2 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"

      />
```